# Attache disk to two instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I created two instances in GCP and one persistent disk.
I would like to attach the disk to both instances.

```
$gcloud compute instances attach-disk vm-1 --disk vm-data --force-attach
$gcloud compute instances attach-disk vm-2 --disk vm-data --force-attach
```

But the disk (vm-data) was viewed only on the last vm-2, it was detaching from vm-1.

Is it possible to attach the disk to several vms?

Comment: You cannot attach a persistent disk to more than one instance in "write" mode. Today at their security seminar Google announced that you can attach a persistent disk to several instances (read-only), even in different regions. I don't know more yet, time to research the announcement.

Comment: Here is the link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/regional-persistent-disk#use_multi_instances

Comment: @John Hanley thk for the link